# error 1001 in installation of Dynamics ax 2012

Tags: axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

IN installation of Dynamics AX 2012 i have an error : " error 1001 " 
i try to install many time but evry time i have this error and this ligne in log file :

> > Install: Error during Setup:
> >     2012-06-08 11:27:25Z        >>Install: An error occurred during the install custom action step within the AOS Server installer

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Install: Only the first eight characters of a custom log name are significant, and there is already another log on the system using the first eight characters of the name given. Name given: 'Microsoft Dynamics AX Workflow', name of existing log: 'Microsoft Web Deploy'.
2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Install:    at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(EventSourceCreationData sourceData)

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           at Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.AosServer.CreateEventSourceIfItDoesNotExistForAxWorkflowRuntimeAos()

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           at Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.AosServer.Install(InstallDriver installDriver)

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           at Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.InstallDriver.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Install: AOS Server End   08/06/2012 11:26:51

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        Rolling back assembly 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Bin\Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.AosServer.dll'.

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        Affected parameters are:

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           aosinstancename = MicrosoftDynamicsAX

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           bypasswarnings = 0

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           assemblypath = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Bin\Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.AosServer.dll

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           aosport = 2712

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           aosexe = Ax32Serv

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           bindir = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Bin#

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           aosinstancenum = 01

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           installtype = notransaction

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           logfile = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Bin\Microsoft.Dynamics.Setup.AosServer.InstallLog

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           aosnettcpport = 8201

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           aoswsdlport = 8101

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           setuplanguage =

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           uilevel = 3

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           action = rollback

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z           aosaccount = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: AOS Server Start 08/06/2012 11:27:01

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: Attempting to remove AOS Server which may have just been partially or fully installed

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: netsh.exe http delete urlacl url=http://+:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback:

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        URL reservation successfully deleted

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: Generating firewall rule name: 'Dynamics AX 6.0 - MicrosoftDynamicsAX (RPC)'

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: Closed port:  'Dynamics AX 6.0 - MicrosoftDynamicsAX (RPC)'.

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: Generating firewall rule name: 'Dynamics AX 6.0 - MicrosoftDynamicsAX (NetTCP)'

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: Closed port:  'Dynamics AX 6.0 - MicrosoftDynamicsAX (NetTCP)'.

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: Generating firewall rule name: 'Dynamics AX 6.0 - MicrosoftDynamicsAX (WSDL)'

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: Closed port:  'Dynamics AX 6.0 - MicrosoftDynamicsAX (WSDL)'.

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: Unlodctr "Dynamics Server"

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback:

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        Counters for Dynamics Server have not been installed yet

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: During Setup of AOS Server an error occurred. Program run: Unlodctr.  Parameters: "Dynamics Server"

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: <<<===== WARNING =====>>>>

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: An error occurred running lodctr.exe.  The following command must be run manually in order for the AOS to run properly: Unlodctr "Dynamics Server"

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z        >>Rollback: AOS Server End   08/06/2012 11:27:02

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z    Common Property Install Path set to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60'.

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z    Installation Path retrieved from registry. Value: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60'

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z    ******************************************************************************************************

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z    Component installation task stopped due to an error.

2012-06-08 11:27:26Z    ******************************************************************************************************

2012-06-08 11:27:27Z    S260FinishedInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like both Microsoft Web Deploy and Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Workflow try to create a custom event log called "Microsof". If you uninstall Microsoft Web Deploy, does AX install succeed?

Comment: thx very much ^_^ i have uninstall Microsoft Web Deploy and installation is success now :)))))))))